# Cant read Key Vault secrets as plain text from Azure PowerShell task in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

​I'm trying to **login to Azure Subscription using Service Principal from Azure DevOps build Pipeline PowerShell task**. 
The reason I need to log in is, I need to execute a few Log analytics queries from the same PowerShell task, hence it requires authentication to the subscription. 
Service Principal ID and Key are in Key Vault as secrets. **I need to read them as plain text to pass and authenticate with Azure Subscription**.

The problem is, I'm not able to read them as plain text or plain string as it comes as an encrypted string value in the Azure DevOps PowerShell task. I can't seem to find ways in order to read them as plain text directly.

I can't use the below command
`(Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $vaultName -Name $secretName).SecretValueText`
because we need to be authenticated already to Azure Subscription to execute the other modules' commands.

Tried the below (i.e) Value for $Encrypted (Service Principal ID)  is in KeyVault as plain text When I used the below it said, Input was not in a correct format

```
$AppId = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Encrypted) $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($AppId) $AppId = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Looking for any other ways to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out an answer for this. I was using PowerShell task type as **AzurePowerShell@2**

But changed that to task: **AzurePowerShell@4** which made things very easier as I already have Service Connection, i can authenticate to subscription using that and also can read and pass the Key Vault secrets  successfully.

you need to mention azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion in build task, it worked simply.

Also this eliminated the requirement of using Service principal and now i can authenticate to subscription using Azure DevOps Service connection.